# Type script - Merging objects in an array by using key Id

Tags: typescript

In Type Script, I have an array of objects,

[  { id: 1,name: 'A' },   {id: 1, name: 'B'},  {id: 2, name: 'X'}, {id: 2, name: 'Y' }, {id: 3, name: 'P'}]

how to  merge the objects in an array by using Key Id.

[{ id: 1, name: ['A', 'B']}, {id: 2, name: ['X', 'Y']}, {id: 3, name: 'P'}]

Comment: You need to try out some logic of your own, on which we can help out if it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Typescript for that. That's typical `reduce` task.

You should write simple reducer that will take each of the pieces of data and build final object, e.g.

```
const reduced = myArray.reduce((memo, current) => {
 // Add new entry, if not present
 if (!memo[current.id]) {
   memo[current.id] = {
     id: current.id,
     name: [current.name],
   }
 } else {
   memo[current.id].name.push(current.name);
 }
}, {});

// To convert above to array, do something like:
const finalArray = Object.values(reduced);
```

The only difference for Typescript would be proper type casting here. You can create interfaces for each array element before and after reducing, e.g.

```
type arrayElt {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

type reducedElt {
  id: number;
  name: string[];
}
```

And then use it with array:

```
const myArray: arrayElt[] = /.../ // Here you have your array
```

After reducing:

```
const reducedArray: reducedElt[] = /.../ // Here reducing code from above
```

Please adjust names and try to glue types together - this should be, however, a good starting point ;)

**EDIT**: As you seem to need to leave objects as plain objects if there's only one representant of particular `id`, you have to use union for types (as particular property may be either `string[]` or `string`). I'll leave you to it, so you can tinker and figure it out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It can be simply achieved using `reduce` function

```
collection.reduce((a, b) => {
  const {id, name} =  b
  let instance = a.find(i => i.id == id);
  !instance ?
    a.push({id, name: [name]}): 
    instance.name.push(name);
  return a 
}, [])
```

---

Other way to achieve this would be using `Map`

```
// find unique keys using Map
var uniqueIds = [...new Set(collection.map(item => item.id))]
// loop over the collection and create final result
uniqueIds.map(id => ({
  id,
  name: collection.filter(i=> i.id == id).map(f => f.name)
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add all the keys to a set where each key is unique and then filter the structure for each key in the set and build a new structure.
in pseudo code:

```
set = array.map(x => x.id)
new arrayValue
for each (id in set){
value = array.filter(x => x.id == id).map(x => x.name)
arrayValue.add({"id":id, "name": value})
}

return ArrayValue
```